# Using one SDL2 renderer for multiple classes

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have been having difficulty trying to link one renderer to multiple files. I have tried using a static renderer but I have had issues with this. My question is what are some ways of using the same renderer in multiple classes and files to help with memory use. I am on Linux if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference member variable in each of the classes, initialize the renderer in your `main()` and pass the reference to the classes' constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of those class has a `Render()` method, or something similar, where you need the `SDL_Renderer`, you could pass a reference to an `SDL_Renderer` declared in one place `Class->Renderer(const SDL_Renderer& Renderer )`. However, this will probably mean propagating a `SDL_Renderer` object through various callstacks.

Other way, would be to keep a reference to a `SDL_Renderer` on your classes, and set it in the constructors of those classes. Then use your member reference in any methods needed.

One other way could be to wrap the `SDL_Renderer` in a *singleton*, and in methods you need it, just grab it from the *Singleton*. This way, propagating it through callstacks and keeping a reference on your classes would be avoided.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the second option that you gave. Does that mean you have a separate renderer for each class? If so then you set all of the renderers in the constructor and parameters to the main renderer of that class. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Bradley, No, not a  "separate" render. On your classes, you declare a reference to a SDL_Renderer. Then, in main(), you create a SDL_Renderer* with SDL, standard way. Then, when constructing objects of your classes, you set your class` SDL_Renderer reference to the one created in main(). Being a reference, it is the same object, not a separate one.